# Variable from a row for filter Transformation in Informatica Powercenter

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Friends , I need help and I need to get a parameter from the database and occupy it as a filter in the main source .

[PowerCenter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PF35h.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to normal join the two tables using DEPT_ID=PARAMVALUE. You can do the join either in SQ override query or using a joiner transformation.